# Testing Fragments with Robolectric 3.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, junit, robolectric

I have two fragments attached to an activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =    
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content,loginFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }

   public void userReg(View view){
    RegisterFragment regFragment = new RegisterFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = 
    fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack("added");
    fragmentTransaction1.replace(android.R.id.content,regFragment);
    fragmentTransaction1.commit();
   }

}
```

The registration fragment attached via a button. Now I want to test both of them in robolectric 3.0.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk = 21)

public class MainActivityTest {
MainActivity activity;
@Before
public void setUp(){
      activity= Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
}

@Test
public void shouldNotBeNull(){
    assertNotNull(activity);
    LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    startFragment(loginFragment);
    assertNotNull(loginFragment);
   }

 @Test
public void loginFragmentShouldNotBeNull(){
    RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
    startFragment(registerFragment);
    assertNotNull(registerFragment);

   }
   @Test
   public void registerFragmentShouldNotBeNull(){
    RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
    startFragment(registerFragment);
    assertNotNull(registerFragment);

   }
 }
```

These line complain

```
        startFragment(loginFragment);
        startFragment(registerFragment);
```

saying that startFragment(android.app.Fragment) can not be applied in LoginFragment and Register fragment respectively.

For both fragments I import

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

so this is causing the problem. I could have fix this issue,by using fixed fragments,but how about using dynamic ones?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The error described above is fixed. I just added

```
import static org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment;
```

However,when I run the test I get another exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil$FragmentUtilActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

at fragments.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:64)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:144)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:30)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:105)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:293)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:143)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.enqueueMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:126)
at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java)
at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1557)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:654)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:621)
at org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(SupportFragmentTestUtil.java:17)
at team.football.ael.MainActivityTest.loginFragmentShouldNotBeNull(MainActivityTest.java:34)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:527)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:265)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:191)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:56)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:157)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)



java.lang.ClassCastException: 

org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.
SupportFragmentTestUtil$FragmentUtilActivity 
cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

at fragments.RegisterFragment.onCreateView(RegisterFragment.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:144)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:30)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:105)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:293)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:143)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.enqueueMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:126)
at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java)
at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1557)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:654)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:621)
at org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(SupportFragmentTestUtil.java:17)
at team.football.ael.MainActivityTest.registerFragmentShouldNotBeNull(MainActivityTest.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:527)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:265)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:191)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:56)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:157)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

**EDIT 2**

This is my RegisterFragment

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {
private SessionManager session;
EditText etEmail, etUsername, etPassword,etConfirmPassword;
String email, userName, userPass,confirmPassword;
Button registerButton;

public RegisterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    etEmail = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    etUsername = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    etPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.user_pass);
    etConfirmPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.confirm_pass);
    registerButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
    // Session manager
    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User ites already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Welcome.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            userName = etUsername.getText().toString();
            userPass = etPassword.getText().toString();
            confirmPassword = etConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

            if(userPass.equals(confirmPassword)){

                registerUser(email, userName, userPass, confirmPassword);

            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Passwords don't match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}
private void registerUser(final String email, final String userName,
                          final String password,final String confirmPassword) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request

    //HttpsTrustManager.sssMethod();
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";


    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("success")) {



                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("id","");
                    editor.putString("email", email);
                    editor.putString("user_name", userName);
                    editor.putString("user_pass", password);
                    editor.putString("confirm_pass", confirmPassword);


                }

                else if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("fail")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id","");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("user_name", userName);
            params.put("user_pass", password);
            params.put("confirm_pass", confirmPassword);
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fragments inherit from "Support fragments" (the ones from android support library), but your `startFragment()` function expects regular fragments. You can use [`SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment, activityClass)`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/support/v4/SupportFragmentTestUtil.html)

Support library allows to use fragments on API levels where no fragments were supported yet. If your application is expected to run on API 11 and above (Android 3) - you can derive your fragments from `android.app.Fragment` directly

Comment: But now I get another exception.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.robolectric.shadows.support.v4.SupportFragmentTestUtil$FragmentUtilActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: Need to see the stack trace

Comment: The exception is thrown from your code in `RegisterFragment`. Seems there you are trying to cast the activity instance to `AppCompatActivity`. Robolectric creates its own activity for fragment testing, which does not derive from `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: In the register fragment I import the toolbal like this.((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

Comment: I think anyway it's better to refactor the code in such way that Fragment will not assume anything about containing activity. Is there a reason why you set the toolbar from the fragment and not from the activity itself? I don't think it's a good idea for the fragment to be responsible on the activity's toolbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116548/discussion-between-denis-itskovich-and-theo).

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But if I don't do the toolbar thing from my fragments then,the toolbar will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but for others, this works well for androidx.fragment.app.Fragment and robolectric 4:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class YourFragmentTest {

    lateinit var yourFragment: YourFragment

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity::class.java)
            .create()
            .start()
            .resume()
            .get()

        yourFragment = YourFragment()
        activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            add(yourFragment, "YourFragment")
            commit()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testYourMethod() {
        assertTrue(yourFragment.YourMethod())
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have access to the Activity (ie: multi module project where I want to test my fragment but with a fake activity like Espresso is doing with `launchFragmentInContainer<>()` is there any way with robolectric?